# How can I profile the latency of WPF's Dispatcher?

Tags: wpf, performance, profiling, dispatcher

In the quest to keep interfaces responsive I'd like to know which tasks on the Dispatcher/message pump take too long. This includes both WPF-internals as well as stuff I push on the Dispatcher by the way of BeginInvoke().

I've already thought about wrapping BeginInvoke() to measure this for me, but this captures only my own code and I fear that it might be too much overhead.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Why not subscribe to the events in the `Dispatcher.Hooks` property (`DispatcherHooks` class).
There is an `OperationPosted` event and an `Operationcompleted` event

Comment: Looks very interesting. I need to have a look at that one!

Comment: Sadly this only shows when the operation is posted to the dispatcher, but not when execution is started, so this is only half of the necessary functionality.

Comment: OperationStarted was introduced in .Net 4.5 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherhooks.operationstarted(v=vs.110).aspx